# <div class="well"> Not Displayed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to create a well for my `<h1>` tag, and I am pretty sure that I do have the correct syntax, but it is not displayed. Can someone take a look and see what I did wrong?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="well">
        <h1 class="text-center">FRONT PAGE NEWBS</h1> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you're not seeing the text at all ?

Comment: the snippet is working.

Comment: @adeneo - I am seeing the text, I am just not seeing the well.

Comment: what do you mean by `the well`? do you mean a place (https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTwdlPY9WbTRkfHKZSiA7pTX5teO0jBEAcGTXyMuRgFd0bTpcS)?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_well&stacked=h maybe it is what you're looking for

Comment: Yes, but I want my h1 tag nested inside my well, and i know that is possible

Answer (score 3):

You should put a css style in your "well" div class for it to be visible like a border or you can add a background-color on it:

```css
.well {
border-style:solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="well">
        <h1 class="text-center">FRONT PAGE NEWBS</h1> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @RobGouldJr You're welcome, you can check my answer as accepted so that everyone who will encounter the same problem in the future will know that this answer is the solution to your question and will also help them. Thank you and best regards :)

Comment: @RyuRoble what's the benefit of bootstrap well if we have to write our own css on it for its border display? Does it just give `background-color` and `padding`, if this is the solution wouldn't it be better to use `border p-2` instead of `well`